# C++ & Qt : A slider like in Adobe After Effects

Tags: c++, qt, slider, after-effects

I'm quite new to C++ & Qt, but I would like to implement sliders like in After Effects in an opensource project i'm working on.
I mean, not a "visual" slider (a bar, like at the left of the pic), but 
a numeric value, which is shown like an hyperlink; 
and which change if you click & slide right or left.
You can either slide on it or click it and directly enter the value.

[image: kind of this]
<sub>(source: [pencil2d.org](https://www.pencil2d.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/sliders-example.jpg))</sub>

Any ideas ?

Comment: I'm not an expert with it, but you can take a look into [Qt Style Sheets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html).  It **might** get things close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert either, but this may help you.

It sounds like you want to create your own widget. 
Then you should subclass QWidget, reimplement mouseEvents (to make it respond to vertical "drags") and paintEvents(to make it look the way you want it to look), give it the signals you need. If you don't want to start from scratch, maybe sublcassing QLineEdit you gain some steps. [Look this trhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522474/creating-pretty-qt-custom-widgets), and [this tutorial](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405227&seqNum=2). This last is a real "eye opener", if you take the time to understand it thoroughly. Good luck!